# trying to use the mutex in an Arc<Mutex<T>> with a Condvar

Tags: rust

further along in trying to port my c++ timer queue to rust. Reading a lot of other peoples code, the rust library etc I came up with this scheme

I have an outer struct that clients use. It is simply a wrapper around an inner implementation. So I have

```
type QIFunc = Box<dyn Fn() -> () + Send>;

pub struct TimerQueueItem {
    when: Instant,
    name: String,
    what: QIFunc,
}

struct _TimerQueue {
    running: bool,
    stop: bool,
    condvar: Condvar,
    queue: Vec<TimerQueueItem>,
}

struct TimerQueue {
    inner: Arc<Mutex<_TimerQueue>>,
}
```

There is a dedicated thread that picks things off this queue and runs them. Works fine without the timing, what I need to do is a classic condvar thing

```
lock cv -> is queue empty -> wait. else pick item off queue (queue is sorted by due time)
look at item -> is it due yet, yes run it, no lock cv till it is due
while sleeping a new thing gets posted, so notify the cv to wake up thread and look at head of queue again.
```

I want to use the mutex thats in my `Arc<Mutex<_TimerQueue>>` since thats the logical queue lock. But I cannot work out how to get at it in such a way that it will compile.

I have this

```
impl TimerQueue {
    fn thr(&self) -> () {
        let inner = self.inner.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {

            loop {
                //let tqi:TimerQueueItem;
                loop {
                  
                    let tqimp = &match inner.lock() {
                        Ok(tqimp) => tqimp,
                        _ => continue,
                    };

                    while !tqimp.stop && tqimp.queue.is_empty() {
                        tqimp.condvar.wait(xxx);
                    }

                    if tqimp.stop {
                        return;
                    }

                    let now = Instant::now();
                    let tqi = &tqimp.queue[0];

                    let due = tqi.when;
                    if due > now {
                        let wait = due - now;
                        tqimp.condvar.wait_timeout(xxx, wait);

                        let tqi = &tqimp.queue[0];
                        let now = Instant::now();
                        let due = tqi.when;
                        if due <= now {
                            (tqi.what)();
                        }
                    } else {
                        let tqi = &tqimp.queue[0];
                        (tqi.what)();
                    
                    }
                }
              //  (tqi.what)();
            }
        });
    }
```

but cannot work out what I need to put in the cv wait calls (where there is xxx at the moment). I have tried &, * clone,,,,. I am stuck. (The commented out code is me trying to pull out the execution of the 'what' to be outside the lock, stuck on that too but I am sure I can work that one out)

EDIT:

heres the entire source

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Instant;

type QIFunc = Box<dyn Fn() -> () + Send>;

struct TimerQueueItem {
    when: Instant,
    name: String,
    what: QIFunc,
}

struct _TimerQueue {
    running: bool,
    stop: bool,
    condvar: Arc<Condvar>,
    queue: Vec<TimerQueueItem>,
}

pub struct TimerQueue {
    inner: Arc<Mutex<_TimerQueue>>,
}




impl TimerQueue {
    fn thr(&self) -> () {
        let inner = self.inner.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {

            loop {
                //let tqi:TimerQueueItem;
                loop {
                  
                    let mut tqimp = &match inner.lock() {
                        Ok(tqimp) => tqimp,
                        _ => continue,
                    };
                    let cv = tqimp.condvar.clone();
                    while !tqimp.stop && tqimp.queue.is_empty() {
                        cv.wait(xxx);
                    }

                    if tqimp.stop {
                        return;
                    }

                    let now = Instant::now();
                    let tqi = &tqimp.queue[0];

                    let due = tqi.when;
                    if due > now {
                        let wait = due - now;
                        cv.wait_timeout(xxx, wait);

                        let tqi = &tqimp.queue[0];
                        let now = Instant::now();
                        let due = tqi.when;
                        if due <= now {
                            (tqi.what)();
                        }
                    } else {
                        let tqi = &tqimp.queue[0];
                        (tqi.what)();
                    
                    }
                }
              //  (tqi.what)();
            }
        });
    }

    fn set(&self, f: QIFunc, n: String, when: Instant) {
        let qi = TimerQueueItem {
            what: f,
            name: n,
            when: when,
        };

        let mut inner = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        inner.queue.push(qi);
        inner.queue.sort_by_key(|k| k.when);
    }
    fn new() -> TimerQueue {
        let inner = Arc::new(Mutex::new(_TimerQueue {
            queue: Vec::new(),
            running: false,
            stop: false,
            condvar: Arc::new(Condvar::new()),
        }));
        TimerQueue { inner: inner }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = || {
        println!("hello");
    };
    let y = || {
        println!("hello2");
    };

    let tq = TimerQueue::new();

    tq.set(Box::new(x), String::from("yo"), Instant::now());
    tq.set(Box::new(y), String::from("yo"), Instant::now());

    thread::sleep_ms(10000);
}
```

Comment: Concurrency noob here, it sometimes helps to get something compiling: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a15b7963cdfa6296f7f7faf15aefbd16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you should put the `MutexGuard` that was returned by `lock`, which in your case is `tqimp`. But you can't because that would require a mutable borrow (in the parameter) at the same time as another borrow (to access `tqimp.condvar`). You will need to either store the `CondVar` outside the queue or to use an `Arc`:

```
struct _TimerQueue {
    running: bool,
    stop: bool,
    condvar: Arc<Condvar>,
    queue: Vec<TimerQueueItem>,
}
```

Then when you want to use it:

```
let mut tqimp = match inner.lock() { // tqimp can't be a reference
        Ok(tqimp) => tqimp,
        _ => continue,
    };
let condvar = tqimp.condvar.clone();
tqimp = condvar.wait (tqimp).unwrap();
```

Note that `condvar.wait` consumes `tqimp` and returns a new `MutexGuard` (because it releases the mutex until the condition triggers, then locks it again before returning).

Comment: does not compile. "expected struct `std::sync::MutexGuard`, found reference" on the wait calls

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: does not compile for the same reason, its the call to wait that fails. the unwrap you suggest comes after that call. I appreciate your help. I will edit the q to include the whole source.

Comment: I didn't just add an unwrap, I also _removed_ a reference in the `let mut tqimp = …` line.

Comment: take yr bonus :-). I cannot work out how to hoist the tqi outside the lock tho, I want to run the requested function without a lock on the queue. I will post another question

Comment: heres the final code - a review would be great https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247327/port-of-my-c-timer-queue-to-rust